# Power BI - How to have a calculated column and place it in a merged cell?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and with the limited time given, I am stuck at how to come up with:

1. How to specifically place the date measures in their specific cell and put it in one column?
2. How can I merge the cells under the Total column?
3. How to add all the numbers from the Type1 and Type2 columns and place it in the merged cell in #2?

Any clues/direction/links on how to achieve the Target Table B below will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exactly do what you are after. PowerBI allows you to rapidly put amazing visuals together however that comes at the price of lack of (easy) flexibility. You could build your own [custom visual](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/custom-visualization/) or look in [App Source](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=power-bi) for a visual that does this, or build the Visual in some other tool (via custom code).

However, I'd recommend sticking with the PowerBI matrix, which will give you a cascading drill down and work out how best to align your data to it and other out of the box visuals. Once you start to delve in to convoluted work-arounds to give users data in exactly the format they request you start to burn a lot of time. Look for alternatives to tell the data's story and work with your end-user to buy in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna share that I have resolved my problem not using one type of visualization, but through using 3 different visualizations in Power BI. I used:

- 1 Table visual for Date column
- 1 Table visual for Total column
- 1 Matrix visual for the Code+Type mapping and counts

I also used DAX function to get the Date format and another DAX function used for both Total and Code+Type counts(to filter data according to the specified date).

Thanks for the response, @Murray and @RADO.